# Using xcopy or copy for a single file from multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

So in the batch script I'm building I am taking a single file from a folder, copying it over to a destination folder, and renaming it based on the number of times that the script has been looped. Essentially I need to take a file that's named the samething from a bunch of different folders spread across multiple computers at times and copy them into a new folder to work with. I've read up on xcopy and copy as that seemed like the thing to use but I haven't been able to find anything that lets me tell it to only copy over a single named file. I've posted what I have so far for the script below with commented lines for the sections I haven't figured out:

```
ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

ECHO Note: Your combined permission list cvs can be found in the desktop folder

SET /A #=-1
:start

SET /A #+=1

:again    
ECHO Please input the file path to the permissionoutput.txt
SET /p permissionoutputpath=

SET "sourcefolder=%permissionoutputpath%"
SET "destinationfolder=C:\Users\kayla\Desktop\HOLDER-CombinedPermissionsLists"
IF not exist "%sourcefolder%\permissionoutput.txt" Echo file not found&goto again
copy "%sourcefolder%\permissionoutput.txt" "%destinationfolder%\permissionoutput%#%.txt"

ECHO Add another file to combine: y or n?
SET /p addanotherfile=
if %addanotherfile%==y goto :start
```

UPDATE: Code corrected with answer to be fully functional for use as a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET /A #=-1
:start

SET /A #+=1

:again    
ECHO Please input the file path to the permissionoutput.txt
SET /p permissionoutputpath=

SET "sourcefolder=%permissionoutputpath%"
SET "destinationfolder=C:\Users\kayla\Desktop\HOLDER-CombinedPermissionsLists"
IF not exist "%sourcefolder%\permissionoutput.txt" Echo file not found&goto again
copy "%sourcefolder%\permissionoutput.txt" "%destinationfolder%\permissionoutput%#%.txt"

ECHO Add another file to combine: y or n?
SET /p addanotherfile=
if /i "%addanotherfile%"=="y" goto start
```

`#` is a legitimate variable-name. It's initialised to `-1` then incremented on each loop through `:start` so the first value it will have when it's *used* is 0. (If you want to start at `1` just initialise it to `0` instead)

Next - your `sets` - **BUT** spaces are significant in a string `set` command are would be included in the variablename/value assigned if present in the `set` instruction. "quoting the assignment" ensures any stray trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned.

Well - next, make sure the file exists and if it doesn't, then produce a message and loop back to `:again` which bypasses the increment of `#`.

Otherwise, simply copy the file. You're aware of its sourcename, and your destinationname is constructed by including `%#%` to include the current value of `#` (all batch variables without exception are strings - the `set /a` instruction merely converts from string to binary to perform the required calculation, then converts the result back to a string for storage in the environment.)

Finally, interpreting the request to add another file. `if /i` makes the comparison case-insensitive. Since you have no direct control over the user's response, "quoting each side" ensures the `if` syntax isn't violated in case the user enters "yup sure 'nuff" or some other unexpected response.

The leading colon is *not* required in a `goto`. I prefer to omit it to keep conguity with the `call` command where no-colon means an external routine will be called and a colon means the routine is in this batch file.